# Justify choice of polynomia based on statistically significant result?

Tags: regression, model-selection, nonlinear, polynomial

I am using an OLS.
The variable of interest is *Nth day to the end of the year* (discrete variable).
I would like to represent the relationship between y and *Nth day to the end of the year with a polynomia*. And I try the following:

1. I introduce this variable as a 1st degree polynomia in the OLS,
   there is no statistical significant effect.
2. I use the 2nd degree polynomia, there is still no effect for
   neither of the polinomya elements.
3. I use a 3rd degree polynomia there is a statistically significant
   effect, for all the elements of the polynomia. Also, the signs of
   the coefficients are: B1*x - B2*x^2 + B3*x^3
4. I use a 4th degree polynomia or more, there is no effect.

In each model specification, the other covariates are always the same.
The R2 does not change much from one model to the other (+0.003 in the third model, with respect to the others)
I do not think I can justify the choice of model 3. on the ground that the results are stat sign, while in all the other model specifications they are not, without having previously explained why I should expect a cubic relationship between y and the indep. var. of interest.

Or could I? 
For instance, in research discontinuity design--parametric version--you run model specifications with different polynomia of order Nth of the running variable and then you choose the specification that better fits the data.

**PS**

My y is "yearly wage" and "Nth day to the end of the year" is the day of birth with 1st January=364 and 31st December=0. I am studying the relative age effect on individual yearly wages and I have a short panel dataset (that I am pooling, and use clustered standard error on individuals). [I apologize I have not mentioned it in the first version of this post]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would be better served by modelling (inferential) the observed Y ( not the cumulative) and use day-of-the-week , week-of-the-month , month-of-the year , lead and lag effects of holidays/events, possible level shifts , possible local trends and possibel ARIMA structure reflecting unknown/unspecified causal variables . When you have a reasonable model then accumulate the forecasts and present the (descriptive)results in terms of the annual cumulative versus the nth day of the year. See http://www.autobox.com/pdfs/capable.pdf slide 43- .. for an example of daily modelling. The approach you are currently using is definitely not useful ( as you are finding out ! ).

Comment: My y is "yearly wage" and "Nth day to the end of the year" is the day of birth with 1st January=364 and 31st December=0. I am studying the relative age effect on individual yearly wage and I have a short panel dataset (that I am pooling, and use clustered standard error on individuals). I am not sure the model you are suggesting fits this situation (and this would totally be my fault, because I have not provided necessary details)

Comment: I am personally unaware of any feasible solution to your problem.